# How many opamps does it take to find the peak amplitude of a signal?

Tags: operational-amplifier

I'm a beginner with EE and trying to find the peak **amplitude** of an electric guitar signal (0-300mV) using an Arduino's 0-5v ADC. I'm going to use the data to pulse lights in accordance with each strum of the guitar.

I've figured out so far that I need to use op-amps to:

1. Rectify the 0-300mv AC signal (full or half wave)
2. Amplify the signal to 0-5v
3. Use a voltage peak finder to locate the peak
4. Use a buffer to protect against impedance (not sure if I need this?)

I've found circuits that use op-amps to do all of these, and they work fine, however they are all independent of each other.

**My Question:** is how do I combine all of these together into one circuit and how many op-amps should I really need.  My approach initially was just to daisy chain everything, but I'm not sure that's the correct approach. Also, most of these use a buffer op-amp as the last step, do I really need one if I'm sending the signal into an ADC?

Comment: If you always amplify the signal to 0-5 V, then find the peak, won't the peak amplitude always be 5 V?

Comment: It will vary based on how hard you strum the guitar. After rectification some quiet guitar picking could be 0-50mv, but if you strum hard the peaks can get up to 300mv. So I'm saying the possible max would change from 300mv to 5v after amplification.

Comment: one... tu-whooo... (crunch) three... the world may never know.

Comment: Daisy chain means to drop something off and then having the same thing continue on it's way to the next drop off point (not just in electronics either). If you're connecting things end-to-end so something through multiple stages that's called cascading.

Answer (score 2):

I think you can do all of this with just two op-amps (although someone will probably correct me).

[image: Opamps for guitar]

The first stage is the peak detector and decay. The op-amp is wired to emulate a perfect diode. We take the feedback signal from after the diode so that the op-amp drives hard enough to overcome the voltage drop of the diode. Being a peak detector, it doesn't really eed a rectified signal. The capacitor holds the peak value, while the resistor decays it. You can make the decay slower by choosing a larger capacitor and resistor. And vice versa.

The second stage is simply 15x gain. It has low output impedance.

Comment: That scheme is wrong if I'm right, because when the signal is inverted the first opamp will saturate...do you agree?

Comment: @clabacchio - It's a good point. I wasn't sure about the OP's spec, because it said 0-300mv, which sounds like it doesn't go below 0v. Or he can use a dual power supply.

Comment: This is wrong.  You are not amplifying the peak detected signal.

Comment: This is the best idea. Two op amps make it easy to adjust and understand, plus I'll probably be using a dual package anyway. I had to modify your schematic a bit for it to work right.  I changed the second stage's input to come from after the diode instead of before.

Comment: @OlinLathrop - Well spotted.

Comment: @uberdanzik - I have corrected the schematic.

Comment: @Rocket: Better now.  Downvote removed.

Comment: This circuit gives the __peak__ amplitude of the input signal, not the __average__ amplitude, as the title and the first sentence of the question ask for. Anyway.

Comment: @Telaclavo: You're right, I apologize for that. I've changed the title now to reflect I was looking for the peak.

Comment: But Telaclavo may have a point. I wonder if you want peak or average.

Comment: Rocketmagnet, I tried to edit, but the page doesn't let me change just one character. Please change "15x" in your text to "16x" (which is the gain you have with 1 k and 15 k). Thanks.

Comment: Regarding average vs peak, I would say that what we have in our ears is not a peak detector, but something closer to an average detector. Peak detection makes sense at the input of a recording device, to detect saturation and loss of information, but in this application, the average (or better, the logarithm of the average) will be more correlated to our perceived volume. Peak detection would just mask a lot of information carried by the lower-amplitude components. Old mechanical vumeters reacted mostly to average, and new LED-based ones may show either one of those two things.

Comment: the nitpicker adds: this circuit finds the peak *positive* amplitude of the signal; signals with 2nd harmonics will have their negative halves ignored.

Answer (score 2):

Here's another precision full wave rectifier. [Full wave amp](https://sound-au.com/appnotes/an001.htm)

[image: Single Supply Precision Rectifier (B-B/ TI)]

<sup>Image from Rod Elliott at Elliott Sound Products</sup>

Personally you can do a lot of signal conditioning with HEX CMOS inverters with each buffer having an open loop gain of 1000. A log amp is useful if you want to regulate Light intensity with log of input amplitude similar to hearing response.
You can use a State Variable Filter to create bandpass, low pass and high pass for 3 channel or use a chain of gyrator BP filters with quad OA's and make one light per note or one per octave. Again it all depends what you want to do.

Comment: +1 -- this circuit detects both positive and negative peaks of waveforms.

Comment: TY @pipe for the link update

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [this](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/28807/op-amp-rectifier-transfer-function-and-output-impedance/28812#28812): it's a rectifier, that you can use both to find the envelop of the curve, and to amplify it.

[image]

You have to set the resistors such as the gain is the desired one (you can use a pot to set it), and the capacitor to minimize the ripple. Note that the RC constant will determine the responsivity of the circuit, so you'll have to find the optimal value for you.

Comment: Damn, you did it in one. Shoulda been obvious.

Comment: @Rocketmagnet I didn't :) I shamelessly took the schematic from another question :)

Comment: Your output RC constant will largely depend on something external to the circuit (as is the input resistance of the ADC input). Also, the maximum gain for that is 11, and the OP needs 16.8.

Comment: @Telaclavo but I've specified that he can change the components to fit his needs, this schematic is taken from another question. And the RC constant will be quite fine if he feeds the signal to the ADC

Comment: Everything there that the OP asked for, except a buffer. And if his ADC needs little enough input current that the error caused by its draining the capacitor is okay, then he doesn't really need the buffer.

Comment: the nitpicker adds: this circuit finds the peak *positive* amplitude of the signal; signals with 2nd harmonics will have their negative halves ignored.

Answer (score 1):

Since you just want to turn on and off LEDs, and don't need hi-fidelity, this should work for you. The opamp amplifies only the positive range of your input signal, and therefore **it does the rectification without needing any diode** and, at the same time, it provides a voltage gain. The opamp will go into and out of saturation constantly, with the corresponding penalty in its frequency response but, I repeat, since you don't need hi-fi, this shouldn't be any problem.

R1 = 4.7 kohm (to limit input current when Vin is negative)

R2 = 9310 ohm

R3 = 590 ohm (gain will be the 5/0.3=16.8 that you need)

R4 = 1 kohm

C1 = 47 uF (R4 and C1 will low pass filter at fc=3.4 Hz, good for a vu-meter)

C2 = 1 uF 0805

U1 = [AD8615AUJZ](http://uk.farnell.com/analog-devices/ad8615aujz/op-amp-precision-rri-o-smd-8615/dp/9079408) (with rail-to-rail input and output)

Notice that this circuit does not perform peak detection. Vout is the average of the positive cycles of Vin. That is proportional to the *average amplitude* of the input signal, which is what the OP wanted. So, in fact, Vout will be at most 2.5 V for full-scale, 50% duty ratio square wave input, but linearity will be better than with a peak detector, because that is nonlinear. The reduced Vout range can be easily compensated:

a) In software.

b) In hardware, applying 2.5 V to the VREF input of the Arduino.

[image: Schematic]

Comment: With that circuit the range goes also to 5 V. And eventually he can use the LED itself as rectifying element

Comment: @clabacchio No, Vout goes to an analog input of an Arduino, he said.

Comment: I do need high fidelity. These LEDs will be pulsing/fading to the guitar's dynamic activity like a light show. Hard strum / light strum should equal Bright pulse / Dim pulse.

Comment: @uberdanzik 1) Clearly, you don't know what hi-fidelity means. Hi-fidelity means something like <= 0.01% THD which, I repeat, makes no sense to drive vu-meter LEDs. 2) This circuit is the most linear of the 3 answers that I see here. 3) You wrote "trying to find the __average__ amplitude", but then selected a circuit that gives you the __peak__ amplitude, so you don't know the difference between them, either. 4) You shouldn't write "How many opamps does it take...", if you later select a solution that does not use the minimum possible number of opamps. Anyway, good to know, for the future.

Comment: @Telaclavo you're right about high-fidelity, but I'm quite sure that for "average amplitude" he means the envelope of the curve, which basically can be obtained with a fast peak detector

Comment: Average implies a time constant or better , an interval of RMS samples. The next best is audio BW of 10kHz with a quasi-peak average defined by ITU standards.

Answer (score 0):

[In the 60's we used filters , triacs and lights to sound .. Light organ .. million ways depending what you want to do](http://www.google.ca/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=light%20organ%20schematic&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8&redir_esc=&ei=5zeXT86zGMqBgAeus7z7DQ)

Wasn't trying to be trite, but the question is fallacious and assumes incorrectly that you need Op Amps to detect the peak amplitude. @uberdanzik  For example 2 transistors in emitter follower NPN then PNP with Caps on emitter will detect peak without offset and buffer it. I hope you understand.