# Adding decay (fall-off) to comparator circuit

Tags: capacitor, operational-amplifier

Following this circuit:
[image]

I'm trying to create a slow decay of the peak, like so:
[image]

Op-amp output is controlling a dimmer pin of a LED driver.
I want the LED to fade out smoothly after a bang.

Comment: circuit via the great [afrotech](http://afrotechmods.com/tutorials/2011/11/28/op-amp-comparator-tutorial-and-clapper-circuit/)

Comment: i *think* i found a solution, in the next afrotech [tutorial](http://afrotechmods.com/tutorials/2011/11/28/op-amp-comparator-tutorial-and-clapper-circuit/)...  i will have to play with the values i guess. the orginal is holding it for a few seconds.   http://i.imgur.com/b5I2v.png

Comment: Related question: http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/30632/how-many-opamps-does-it-take-to-find-the-peak-amplitude-of-a-signal

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a peak-detector circuit. If the next stage has a high impedance a simple circuit will do: diode, followed by a capacitor in parallel with a resistor. The RC time will determine your decay time.

[image: simple peak detector]

There are lots of RC time calculators on the web, for instance [here](http://hughestech.com/rc_calculator/).

Comment: got the peak detector part, thanks for the calculator

Answer (score 3):

To complement Wouter's answer here is another option.
If you want to avoid the diode drop that occurs with a passive peak detector, then you can use an active peak detector:

[image: Active peak detector]

We can see in the simulation the full peak voltage is present blue is the input, the green output):

[image: Active peak detector sim]

If there is significant load on the output, then you will probably want to add a buffer (a dual opamp would be good for the complete circuit)

Comment: Yoshco can even re-use his amplifying opamp if he puts the diode between the ompamp output and the 100k resistor (provided that this resistor is high compared to the discharge resistor for the capacitor).